# How to implement Istanbul Coverage with Selenium and Mocha

Tags: typescript, selenium, testing, mocha.js, istanbul

I am using Selenium with Mocha to run my Application tests and I would like to generate the code coverage as well.

I'm trying to add Istanbul to generate it however I think there are some points I didn't get and I don't really know from where should I start. Like the [`istanbul-instrumenter-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/istanbul-instrumenter-loader) module which I don't know if I need in my case ?

Running mocha will open the App on a port let's say 8081 (or even the deployed version) using the webdriver. (I don't think there is much work to do in the main folder - see the project structure below).

Now, under the `Application/tests/uiTests` folder, I want to initialize the directory of my code which is `Application/components`.

I tried using `cwd` in the `nyc` configuration, it didn't work obviously and I guess Istanbul does not see any file since everything is just zero in the displayed result.

Note : There is no webpack file under `tests/uiTests`

This is what I tried in `.nycrc.json`

```json
{
    "extends": "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript", // Since I'm using TS in both App and Tests
    "all": true,
    "extension": ["tsx"],
    "cwd" : "../../components"
}
```

This is how my project looks like

```
-- Application (main folder)
-- package.json
-- webpack.config.json

---- components (=> src)
------ **/*.tsx

---- Tests
------ uiTests <--- you can run mocha here
-------- package.json
-------- .mocharc.json
-------- tsconfig.json
-------- babel.config.js
```

.mocharc.json

```json
{
  "extension": ["ts"],
  "spec": "core/**/*.spec.ts",
  "require": "config/register.ts",
  "timeout": 30000,
  "color": true,
  "reporter": "mocha-junit-reporter",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "mochaFile": "./report/results.xml"
  }
}
```

register.ts

```js
require('core-js/stable');
require('regenerator-runtime/runtime');
require('chromedriver');
require('ts-node/register/transpile-only');
require('source-map-support/register');
const register = require('@babel/register').default;

register({ extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'] });
```

babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = (api) => {
    // Cache configuration is a required option
    api.cache(false);

    const presets = [
        '@babel/preset-typescript',
        '@babel/preset-env',
    ];

    return { presets, sourceType: 'module' };
};
```

uiTests/package.json

```json
{
  "...": "...",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "coverage": "tsc && nyc mocha"
  },
  "directories": {
    "test": "./core"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.14.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.14.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.13.0",
    "@babel/register": "7.13.16",
    "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/assert": "1.5.4",
    "@types/chai": "4.2.18",
    "@types/chromedriver": "81.0.0",
    "@types/mocha": "8.2.2",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "4.0.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.22.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.22.1",
    "assert": "2.0.0",
    "chai": "4.3.4",
    "chromedriver": "91.0.0",
    "core-js": "3.12.1",
    "eslint": "7.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "33.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.3",
    "mocha": "8.4.0",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "nyc": "^15.1.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "0.13.7",
    "selenium-webdriver": "4.0.0-beta.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.19",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "4.2.4"
  },
  "...": "...",
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Getting `istanbul` working

I had the same problem you had months ago. All zeroes in the reports. The problem has to do with the use of ESM modules. It appears that may be your issue too: I see `sourceType: 'module'` in your babel config.

If so, you will need to uses [`@istanbuljs/esm-loader-hook`](https://github.com/istanbuljs/esm-loader-hook) to get mocha to work with Istanbul when using modules.

[Install](https://github.com/istanbuljs/esm-loader-hook) `@istanbuljs/esm-loader-hook` and then invoke mocha like this:

```sh
npx nyc mocha --experimental-loader=@istanbuljs/esm-loader-hook
```

You can see https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/1343 for some troubleshooting steps.

#### A possibly better alternative: `c8`

If you still have trouble getting Istanbul to work, before you spend too much time trying to figure out why, I strongly recommend you try an alternative to istanbul/nyc that uses V8's native coverage facilities and **just magically works**: [c8](https://github.com/bcoe/c8#readme).

It is written by @bcoe, one of the maintainers of nyc/instanbul. When I had trouble with Istanbul, it took me 5 minutes to get c8 to work. It is compatible with Istanbul's reporters and you get the exact same reporting functionality out-of-the-box.

Comment: Zied, did you give this a try? If it didn't work, even c8, can you tell me what happened?

Comment: hey man thanks for your answer. It looks promising. Unfortunately, I didn't tried it yet. Hopefully next week I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: hey no worries. i guess the bounty will get wasted, but nbg. Just so you know, you can get c8 up and running within 5-10 minutes, it's that easy.

Comment: no I can award the bounty after the current week actually

Comment: @ZiedHf since you haven't accepted my answer, I'm thinking it didn't work for you? Curious I want to be able to recommend c8 vs nyc to a friend, and leaning toward c8.

Comment: `@istanbuljs/esm-loader-hook` [no longer works](https://github.com/istanbuljs/esm-loader-hook/issues/6) in Node.js ≥ 16.12.0 due to an incompatible change in the experimental ESM loader hook API.